# Spellcheck content of Document in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have added spell checking by reading contents of a file using powershell script?

This script does my job, but I want to check if there are any external packages or modules available for the same, since it would make the work easier.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem ./Code-Duplication/master.md
$Proofread_text = Get-Content $file.FullName
$Word = New-Object -COM Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Textrange = $Document.Range(0)

#$english = FindLanguage("English (US)")

#$Textrange.LanguageID = $english.ID
$Textrange.InsertAfter($Proofread_text)

<#Handle misspelled words here#>
$file.Name
Write-Output "---------------"
foreach($spell_error in $textrange.SpellingErrors){
    Write-Host $spell_error.Text
}

$Document.Close(0)
$Word.Quit()
```

Comment: So the question is actually `"Is there a PowerShell module for spellchecking documents?"` and nothing else? You added quite a bit of overhead for your question in that case.

Comment: Yes @notjustme that is my question. I wanted to let know, i have done my work before asking question

Comment: I have PS module Check-Spelling , but it seems not working for me

Comment: First of all, you having done your homework is much appreciated and I believe most SO users would agree. That being said, however, still doesn't make this particular question a programming related one.

If you post a question with details on the Check-Spelling module (function?) problems you might have a better chance of getting help with your core issue - reusability.

Another option could be to read up on how you could create advanced functions yourself (see `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`), using the code you already have.

Comment: @notjustme I am a novice in PS program. I would like to enhance my program so that , while doing the spell check, it has to look into a text file for a list of words it can exclude from spell check, is that something possible within my program. Need help on that.